# Extjs and asp.net mvc integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

Is it possible to access .net variables, resources etc. from exjs script. For instance how to perform sth like:

```
 items: [{
            text: '@ResourceClass.Text',
        }
```

or access url by:

```
 items: [{
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Body.htm")',
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work as long as that script is inside a cshtml file. However, the parser can get a bit confused by the similarity of javascript and c# code - when this happens modifying the syntax to

```
url: '@(Url.Content("~/Content/Body.htm"))',
```

usually gets the parser to recognize the c# component correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can mix your .NET code with js code in your views but not in external javascript files and extjs is another js library so you can mix extjs code in your views.

Comment: it doesn't sounds good... I believe to session state i don't have access either, do i?